# Get shelves count, ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, image-processing, vision

I was trying to calculate the number of shelves but I was failing to get the exact count. I tried using a vision framework. It worked on the grid image but on the realtime image it failed.

I was new and not sure about my approach. Please look into it and let me know if I missed something or suggest a way to achieve this.

```
import UIKit
import Vision
enum DetectionTypes {
    case Rectangle
}

extension ViewController {
    //MARK: - Internal Variables
    private var rectanglesDetection: VNDetectRectanglesRequest {
        let request = VNDetectRectanglesRequest { (request, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                guard let observations = request.results as? [VNDetectedObjectObservation] else { fatalError("No Observations found") }
                self.visualizeObservations(observations: observations,type: .Rectangle)
            }
        }
        request.minimumAspectRatio = VNAspectRatio(0.0)
        request.maximumAspectRatio = VNAspectRatio(1.0)
        request.minimumSize = Float(0.1)
        request.maximumObservations = 0
        request.minimumConfidence = 1.0
        return request
    }
    
    //MARK: - Private Methods
    private func visualizeObservations(observations: [VNDetectedObjectObservation], type: DetectionTypes){
        print("No of rectangles: \(observations.count)")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let image = self.gridImageView.image else{ fatalError("Failure in retriving image") }
            let imageSize = image.size
            var imageTransform = CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: 1, y: -1).translatedBy(x: 0, y: -imageSize.height)
            imageTransform = imageTransform.scaledBy(x: imageSize.width, y: imageSize.height)
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, true, 0)
            let graphicsContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
            image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: imageSize))
            
            graphicsContext?.saveGState()
            graphicsContext?.setLineJoin(.round)
            graphicsContext?.setLineWidth(5.0)
            
            switch type {
            case .Rectangle:
                graphicsContext?.setFillColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 1, alpha: 0.3)
                graphicsContext?.setStrokeColor(UIColor.random.cgColor)
                        
            observations.forEach { (observation) in
                let observationBounds = observation.boundingBox.applying(imageTransform)
                graphicsContext?.addRect(observationBounds)
            }
            
            graphicsContext?.drawPath(using: CGPathDrawingMode.fillStroke)
            graphicsContext?.restoreGState()
            
            let drawnImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            self.gridImageView.image = drawnImage
        }
    }
    
    //MARK: - Public Methods
    func createVisionRequest(image: UIImage) {
        guard let cgImage = image.cgImage else {
            return
        }
        
        let requestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: cgImage, orientation: image.cgImageOrientation, options: [:])
        let vnRequests = [rectanglesDetection]
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            do{
                try requestHandler.perform(vnRequests)
            }catch let error as NSError {
                fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}

extension UIColor {
    static var random: UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: .random(in: 0...1),
                       green: .random(in: 0...1),
                       blue: .random(in: 0...1),
                       alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you get ? More shelves counted than expecte ? Less ?

Comment: less count and some objects are counted instead of shelf. Am I doing anything wrong?